# react removing one item from cart when items have the same id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

A user has the ability to add multiple items to cart. Sometimes being the same item twice, threes times, etc. I am having a problem removing one item from a cart when their are others that have the same id. For example, if there are three products of the same items in a cart and a user clicks remove item on just one item all of the items get removed when in reality i only want the item that the user clicked on to get removed.

here is the front end code

```
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.signin);
     const handleRemoveFromCart = (userId, itemId) => {
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:3003/cartItems/${userId}/${itemId}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        };

    {products.map((product) => (
                                <div className="text-[12px] gap-[10px] flex mb-[20px]">
                                    {/* <img className="w-[200px]" src={`data:${cartItem};base64,${Buffer.from(cartItem.image).toString('base64')}`} /> */}
                                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                                        <p className="font-medium">{product.title}</p>
                                        <div className="flex relative">
                                            <p>{product.price}</p>

                                        </div>
                                        <p onClick={() => handleRemoveFromCart(user._id, product._id)}>Remove item x</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
```

here is the backend code

```
router.delete('/cartItems/:userId/:itemId', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, itemId } = req.params;  
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { $pull: { cartItems: { _id: itemId } } },
      { new: true }
    )
      .then((updatedUser) => {
        if (updatedUser) {
          console.log(updatedUser);
          res.status(200).json(updatedUser.cartItems);
        } else {
          res.status(404).json({ error: 'User or item not found' });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server error' });
      });
  });
```

Comment: I think the best approach to this problem would be to associate a quantity with each item added to the cart. This way you remove the item from the cart if quantity === 0, otherwise you can increment or decrement the quantity of an item as you please.

Comment: You can remove by index